# Script to review log files

Tags: python, perl, bash, shell, logging

When I review logs on a server I want to have a quick overview of the type of problems that I'm facing before I got digging deeper. I usually use the below one-liner which reduces the number of log lines I need to review by making each line more generic and keeping only the ones that are unique.

**One-liner**

```
cat /var/log/apache2/error.log | sed 's/.*] \(.*\)/\1/' | sed 's/[0-9]*//g' | sort | uniq
```

**Explanation**

`| sed 's/.*] \(.*\)/\1/'`: removes everything contained within and before the last bracket group which typically corresponds to client/system-specific info such as  `[Mon Dec 05 12:01:03 2011] [error] [client a.b.c.d]`

`| sed 's/[0-9]*//g'`: removes numbers

`| sort | uniq`: only keeps lines that are different.

To give you an idea, on an `/var/log/apache2/error.log` that contains around 500 lines, this filters out to 25 lines. Off course the more generic/similar the log entries, the more the one-liner is effective.

What I'm looking for now is a script (could be `bash`,`perl`,`python` or anything else actually) that could do the same thing but a bit more advanced so as to be even more effective (e.g. obfuscate file paths, alphabetical ids...) and useful (count how many occurrences of each message, % compared to the overall amount of logs...).

**Do you know scripts that do that?**

Comment: take a look at ScanErrLog if you haven't yet

Comment: -1 There are plenty of log analyzers to be found with your favourite search engine. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Agree with above. But if you must roll your own, you'll have to post some sample data that makes concrete the problems you are dealing with. Good luck.

Comment: Sure Google would probably give thousands of results. The reason for asking on StackExchange is that it's validated by the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look at [logwatch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/logwatch/) . it does send you a daily overview of common logfiles. I have only used it for mail logs so far but afaik it can handle apache logs as well.